# Extract the "share link" for each video in the dropbox folder

Tags: javascript, windows, dropbox

I have  set of videos in dropbox folder. Let us say "v1.avi, v2.avi, ....., vn.avi".
I would like to automatically extract the share link for each video in the folder. So, I can use it as a source value of HTML video.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/....../1.avi?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/....../2.avi?dl=0

.
.
.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/....../n.avi?dl=0

How can I do that using Javascript? or is ther any other way to do that? 
I have more than 1000 videos in the folder, and I cannot do that manually!

Comment: Why minus? Good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Dropbox API to get shared links to files programmatically. Using the Dropbox API v2, the relevant endpoint is the new /create_shared_link_with_settings:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings

We recommend using an official SDK if possible, though there isn't currently an official JavaScript SDK for v2.

That being the case, you may want to use [dropbox.js](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js), which uses the Dropbox API v1. I believe the `makeUrl` method is relevant in that case.